# Android ListView 'blinks' / 'flashes' on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview

I have a very simple ListView in my andriod app. However, everytime I call notifyDataSetChanged() on my adapter, it 'blinks'. It works fine, but the ListView flashes. Like goes compeltely white, and then comes back in a fraction of a second. What may be causing this?

I am not sure what code to share as this is a very simple ListView / adapter but if you'd like to see a certain part of the code please let me know.

This is the code that updates the listView:

```
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("recentWithAds", new HashMap<String, Object>(), new FunctionCallback() {
    public void done(Object resp, ParseException e) {
        mLoading = false;
        mSwipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        mArticles.clear();
        mArticles.addAll(articles);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes please show some code. It all depends on from where you are calling your `notifydatSetChanged()`

Comment: It redraws the items in the ListView, it's going to happen.

Comment: @svenoaks Flashing white would mean a redraw with white color, which should not be happening.

Comment: Hope you are not reloading your intent explicitly after calling notifydatasetChanged(). sample code would be helpful though.

Comment: @Jimmy I've updated with the code, does that help?

Comment: @AndroidWarrior I've updated with the code, does that help?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong :(. just a guess, adapter has mArticles. It is possible that articles has large amount of items which is making your redraw take lots of time and you might have been seeing white background during that reload. Can you try adding only few items in mArticles ? if thats the case you need to find some alternative way to add/remove only relevant articles from the list. This is just a guess. may/maynot work.

Comment: @0xSina I'm totally in agreement with @Jimmy, apart from that just check that your `ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground()` isn't called multiple times in very short span of time, that might be a reason too.